# Biblatex: How to sort articles in only one of several bibliographies by year?

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I use biblatex/biber and use several bibliographies for different document types in my document (e.g. one for articles and books, misc for legal documents).The problem is that I can't seem to get to sort one specific bibliography by year("ynt"), while another still needs to be sorted "nyt".

How do I make the documents of only one bibliography sort primarily by year?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

test\autocites[]{test1}[]{test2}[]{test3}[]{test4}

\printbibliography[title={Literatur}, type=book] %this is articles and books, which needs to be sorted NYT
\printbibliography[title={Deutsche Rechtsquellen und Gesetzmaterialien}, type=misc] %this is legal documents, which needs to be sorted YNT.
\end{document}
```

With the following lit.bib

```
@book{test1,
    Author = {{Karl Marx}},
    Title = {Capital},
    Year = {1867}}

@book{test2,
    Author = {Calliess, Christian and Ruffert, Matthias},
    Title = {Kommentar zum EUV/EGV},
    Year = {2007}}

@misc{test3,
    Author = {{BT-Drs. 9/743}},
    Howpublished = {Bundestagsdrucksache 1},
    Year = {1981}}

@misc{test4,
    Author = {{BT-Drs. 9/735}},
    Howpublished = {Bundestagsdrucksache 2},
    Year = {1985}}
```

The result can be seen here:

[image]

The "Literatur" is correctly sorted (by authorname), but I need the other bibliography to be sorted by year. Changing the sorting globally does not help, as I need distinct sorting only for legal documents. Removing the global sorting option and introducing local sorting options did not work, however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to change `sorting=nyt` to `sorting=ynt`?  Year Name Title)?

Comment: thanks for the input! it does work, but is not a solution to my problem. i updated my initial post to cover the entire issue, maybe the problem becomes clearer?

Comment: Please add a minimal document and a couple of sample `.bib` entries to your question. Posting the output is not particularly helpful here, since we need to see what your `.bib` entries are like. To see how to do this for a bibliography question like yours see [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed it again, now it should work and all be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent version of `biblatex` removed the sorting option from `\printbibliography` and move it to `\refcontext`. Thus you have to add the `\refcontext`s for the bibliography you want to display.

Accordingly, the MWE should look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
@book{test1,
    Author = {{Karl Marx}},
    Title = {Capital},
    Year = {1867}}

@book{test2,
    Author = {Calliess, Christian and Ruffert, Matthias},
    Title = {Kommentar zum EUV/EGV},
    Year = {2007}}

@misc{test3,
    Author = {{BT-Drs. 9/743}},
    Howpublished = {Bundestagsdrucksache 1},
    Year = {1981}}

@misc{test4,
    Author = {{BT-Drs. 9/735}},
    Howpublished = {Bundestagsdrucksache 2},
    Year = {1985}}  
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[autocite=footnote, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

test\autocites[]{test1}[]{test2}[]{test3}[]{test4}

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography[title={Literatur}, type=book] %this is articles and books, which needs to be sorted NYT

\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
\printbibliography[title={Deutsche Rechtsquellen und Gesetzmaterialien}, type=misc] %this is legal documents, which needs to be sorted YNT.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Removing a bunch of misplaced backslashes in your code and changing the key answer and sorting style to "\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]" worked for me! Thanks!